# How to upload trumbowyg images to my S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, trumbowyg

I'm using [Trumbowyg](https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg) which is a wysiwyg editor that allows image uploads. It has an [image upload plugin](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/demos/#plugins-upload) which shows how to use Imgur as the image host - however I would like to host my images via AWS S3. How can I do this?

Here is the relevant code for the upload parameters:

```
plugins: {
    // Add imagur parameters to upload plugin for demo purposes
    upload: {
        serverPath: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
        fileFieldName: 'image',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        urlPropertyName: 'data.link'
    }
}
```

Does this format allow for S3 to be a host? I can change the `serverPath` to my S3 bucket URL, but for the rest including the authorization, I'm not too sure.

Any idea how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure, but I think you can create a route in your back-end (controller) which accepts 'fileToUpload' as a request, and then connect with your S3 and upload via your back-end, then return the url:xxx and success:true as json.